# Enlazar rutas correctamente según sean invocadas de un componente u otro con React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

estoy realizando unas prácticas donde tengo que hacer una web de peliculas con una API. Tengo dos componentes (películas y series) que comparten el mismo navegador. Necesito poner un condicional para que la ruta sea una u otra, según se utilice el navegador en el componente películas o en el de series.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element = {<Home/>} exact/>
        <Route path = '/series' element = {<Series/>} exact /> 
        <Route path = '/peliculas' element = {<Movies/>} exact />         
        <Route path = '/:seriesType' element = {<SeriesTv/>} exact />         
        <Route path = '/:moviesType' element = {<MoviesFilm/>} exact />         
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Este es componente del navegador, desde aquí se pasa la ruta al Routes, el primer link funciona perfectamente, el segundo y el tercero siempre me dirigen al componente series, el problema es que no se como indicarle que viene del navegador del componente películas. Lo que sucede es que en la API esa parte de la ruta es la misma "to='/popular'" "to='/top_rated'".

```
export const Navegador = (props) => {
        let {movies} = (props)
        let masVotados = movies ? 'Películas más votadas' : 'Series más votadas';
        let masPopulares = movies ? 'Películas más populares': 'Series más populares';
        let filmOrSerie = movies ? 'Ver series' : 'Ver peliculas';
        let urlFilmOSerie = movies ? '/series' : '/peliculas';
  return (
    <div className='container'>
        
        <div className='container-button'>
                <nav  className='nav-header'>
                    <ul>
                    <NavLink to={urlFilmOSerie}>
                        <li>
                            {filmOrSerie}
                        </li>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to='/popular'>
                        <li>
                            {masPopulares}
                        </li>
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to='/top_rated'>
                        <li>
                            {masVotados}
                        </li>
                    </NavLink>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Este es el componente de las películas, que recibe los parámetros de moviesType y se los paso a la url de la API, despues formo la vista completa con otro componente, pero no creo que haga falta ponerlo.

```
const MoviesFilm = () => {

  const {moviesType} = useParams();
  const [movies,setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=> {
      axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${moviesType}?api_key=9218b9bd6999a8af1b8972bb1b4b815a&language=es-ES`)
      .then(res => setMovies(res.data.results))
      .catch(console.error);        
  },[moviesType]);

  return <div className="container-movies">
      {movies?.map(movie=><Movie key={movie.id} movie={movie}/>)}

  </div>
}
```

Aquí hago exactamente lo mismo, pero con las series. Como podemos observar en la url de la API, la ruta es casi la misma, pero antes de la variable que pongo si que define si es tv o movie.

```
const Series = (props) => {
    const {seriesType} = useParams();
    const [series,setSeries] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=> {
        axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${seriesType}?api_key=9218b9bd6999a8af1b8972bb1b4b815a&language=es-ES`)
        .then(res => setSeries(res.data.results))
        .catch(console.error);        
        },[seriesType]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <Navegador/>
            </div>
            <div  className= 'container-series'>
                {series?.map(serie=><Serie key={serie.id} serie={serie}/>)}  
            </div>
        </div>  
    )
}
```

Estoy seguro que el error esta en el primer código, pero no se como hacer para que cuando estoy en el navegador de las películas se me active la ruta que va a MoviesFilm.
Espero haberme explicado, si tienen alguna duda o quieren ver algo más de código, diganmelo. Por otra parte dejo el enlace del repositorio por si alguien quisiera verlo. Gracias por su ayuda.
https://github.com/jbortweb/peliculas_react_jbortweb

Comment: Por favor, especifica en el título _cuál es la duda en cuestión_. Piénsalo, si otros usuarios llegan a tener un problema similar, ¿cómo encontrarían tu pregunta?

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo cambie. Espero que quede más claro. Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final cree otro navegador, uno para series y otro para peliculas. Tuve que añadir rutas en el archivo app.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/peliculas_react_jbortweb' element = {<Home/>}/>
        <Route exact path = '/series' element = {<Series/>}/> 
        <Route exact path = '/peliculas' element = {<Movies/>}/>         
        <Route exact path = '/tv/:seriesType' element = {<SeriesTv/>}/>        
        <Route exact path = '/movie/:moviesType' element = {<MoviesFilm/>} />    
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

El navegador de películas lo deje así.
Le paso la ruta para que vaya directamente a la de movie.

```
<NavLink to='/series'>
   <li>
     Series
   </li>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to='/movie/popular'>
   <li>
     Películas más populares
   </li>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to='/movie/top_rated'>
   <li>
     Películas más votadas
   </li>
</NavLink>
```

Y en el navegador de series hago exactamente lo mismo.

```
<NavLink to='/peliculas'>
   <li>
     Películas
   </li>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to='/tv/popular'>
   <li>
     Series más populares
   </li>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to='/tv/top_rated'>
   <li>
     Series más votadas
   </li>
</NavLink>
```

Espero que le sirva de ayuda a alguien. Gracias a los que intentaron echar una mano. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

A lo mejor es una toneria lo que digo pero has intentado una ruta como:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element = {<Home/>} exact/>
        <Route path = '/series' element = {<Series/>} exact /> 
        <Route path = '/peliculas' element = {<Movies/>} exact />         
        <Route path = '/series/seriesType' element = {<SeriesTv/>} exact />         
        <Route path = '/peliculas/moviesType' element = {<MoviesFilm/>} exact />         
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Si, lo intente, tambien cambiar la ruta en el componente del navegador y poner el vavLink con el to = movie/popular. Nada me funciona. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a poner un exact en el componente ruta? Asi solo entra en el caso de que la ruta sea exacta

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element = {<Home/>} exact/>
        <Route exact path = '/series' element = {<Series/>} exact /> 
        <Route exact path = '/peliculas' element = {<Movies/>} exact />         
        <Route exact path = '/series/:seriesType' element = {<SeriesTv/>} exact />         
        <Route exact path = '/peliculas/:moviesType' element = {<MoviesFilm/>} exact />         
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hola Suso, si lo puse, esta al final del elemento, he probado de ponerlo al principio por si era eso, pero sigue sin funcionarme.